# Themes in CakePHP 2.0.0-dev

Tags: cakephp, themes, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

Trying to set up a mobile theme in CakePHP 2.0.0-dev, but it isn't working as it did in 1.3. Have there been any changes to the themes implementation in 2.0?

Structure as follows:

```
app/views/themed/mobile/layouts/default.ctp
app/views/themed/mobile/pages/home.ctp
```

Then in app/app_controller.php:

```
public function beforeRender()
{
    if ($this->RequestHandler->isMobile()) {
        $this->view = 'Theme';
        $this->theme = 'mobile';
    }
}
```

Hit the home page... But no mobile site... Just the normal site. No errors, nothing in debug or error logs. No errors, no exceptions. Nothing. As if themes have been deprecated or something.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$this->layout='mobile';
```

That should then display the layout when browsed to by a mobile device.

Comment: you'll need to create your own layout called mobile (or whatever else you like)

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

After looking in cake/libs/view/theme.php, I read this:

> ...You can set `$this->theme` and `$this->viewClass = 'Theme'`...

```
public function beforeRender()
{
    if ($this->RequestHandler->isMobile()) {
        $this->viewClass = 'Theme';
        $this->theme = 'mobile';
    }
}
```

So, looks like a slight change in version 2.0 to the variable name from **$this->view** to **$this->viewClass**.

Works now!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has further issues with this, I have a post with some more information at http://blog.ergatides.com/web-design/themes-in-cakephp-2-0-0/